# Does resizing images down with HTML/CSS produce better results than Fireworks etc.?

Tags: html, css, image

I generally take an image in Fireworks, change it to the right size for the website and then export it for the web as JPG/PNG. This is fine.

I've been noticing that if I use a larger image in my `<img>` tag and then resize it with the CSS `width` property, it will be crisper and clearer than if I resized it in an Adobe product.

Do others get the same experience? E.g.: take an image that’s 100x100, resize to 50x50 in Fireworks, and 50x50 with CSS, and the image looks better with the CSS resize.

I understand the smaller the image the better for site load times etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the browser and the image manipulation program.

When you resize using CSS or HTML, you are asking the browser to do the resizing, instead of supplying a pre-resized image.

Whether the resulting resized image is "clearer" depends on the image, the browser, and the resizing algorithm used (bicubic, bilinear, Lanczos, etc).

For *best* results, you should resize it yourself. You can try a number of different resize algorithms in your image manipulation program. With a browser, you are depending on that browser to supply the right resize algorithm, and you can't guarantee that every visitor will use the same browser...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling

Also, as @PeeHaa already noted, giving the browser the larger image means more loading time. It *also* means more RAM usage in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been noticing if I use a larger image in take and then resize it will CSS width it will be more crisp and clearer. Looks better then resizing in an Adobe Product.

That would be a first.

Generally on the web you should just provide images with the correct dimensions for the best results.

Also as you already said larger image == more loading time (for a relative small image).

**EDIT**

I just checked out out what Fireworks is :) something to create images for the web might not be the best tool for resizing images (I think it does compression too). Have you tried PhotoShop / Illustrator?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the particular browser you're using uses better/more suited for the particular image resizing algorithm that the program you used.

You can take a random image editor like gimp and take a look at resizing option where you can choose one of the interpolation methods available.

Unless your browser is doing some additional image scaling as well.

Answer (score 0):

When using CSS it's entirely based on the browser. Firefox seems to be very good at downsizing the images, but Internet Explorer (at least IE6/7) is horrendous at it.

You may want to try changing your resize method in Photoshop or another graphics editing tool. Fireworks probably uses a fixed algorithm. I find that bicubic resize works best for most cases, though it may be a different case for you if you have sharp edges or crisp lines.

You should also test your images on different screens. I've had cases where a rather "liney" image looked horrible on one screen, but perfect on another.